# reportlab: Smartest way to position page with bookmarkPage

Tags: python, reportlab

I've been using python and reportlab to auto-generate long documents and want to use the PDF outline tree for easy navigation through the document. According to the [docs](https://docs.reportlab.com/reportlab/userguide/ch4_pdffeatures/), `canvas.bookmarkPage` comes with multiple options to adjust the document view after jumping to the destination page. The standard one is a simple page `Fit` to the window. From a user perspective, I would prefer `FitH` (as wide as possible, with destination at the top of the screen) or `XYZ` (keep user zoom level with destination at the top of the screen). When using any fit option except the basic `Fit`, the function call must be provided with the coordinates to arrange the view accordingly.

However, I could not find any explanations, examples, code snippets, or anything on how to figure this out, and it took me a good while to come up with a solution. **So, I want to share this solution here and ask if this is really the best way to do it or if I overlooked something basic.**

The key thing here is `SmartParagraph` which remembers its position after it was drawn. First, I used `flowable.canv.absolutePosition(0,0)` in the `afterFlowable()` method because this is where I needed this information to pass it to `bookmarkPage()`. However, the position was always reported as `0, 0`, so apparently the flowable and/or the canvas have forgotten everything about the position when `afterFlowable()` is reached. So I thought there has to be some point in time when a Flowable knows its position and after investigating the source code I found out that after `draw()`, it still knows where it is.

So: `SmartParagraph` is a subclass of `Paragraph` that stores its position after it is drawn, so that later in the document building process this can be used by any external element for whatever.

The example will create a dummy pdf with 2 headings that do a nice `FitH` zoom and two headings that do the basic `Fit` zoom.

Does anyone have a better idea on how to solve this?

```py
import typing
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle as PS
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.platypus.flowables import Flowable
from reportlab.platypus import PageBreak, Spacer
from reportlab.platypus.paragraph import Paragraph
from reportlab.platypus.doctemplate import SimpleDocTemplate
from reportlab.lib.units import cm


class SmartParagraph(Paragraph):
    def __init__(self, text, *args, **kwds):
        """This paragraph remembers its position on the canvas"""
        super(SmartParagraph, self).__init__(text, *args, **kwds)
        self._pos: typing.Tuple[int, int] = None

    def draw(self):
        super(SmartParagraph, self).draw()
        self._pos = self.canv.absolutePosition(0, 0)

    def get_pos(self) -> typing.Tuple[int, int]:
        return self._pos


class CustomDocTemplate(SimpleDocTemplate):
    def __init__(self, filename, outline_levels: int = 4, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDocTemplate, self).__init__(filename, **kwargs)
        self._bookmark_keys = list()

        if not isinstance(outline_levels, int) and outline_levels < 1:
            raise ValueError("Outline levels must be integer and at least 1")
        self._outline_levels = {f'Heading{level+1}': level for level in range(outline_levels)}
        # Map of kind:      Heading1 -> 0
        # Heading 1 is level 0, I dont make the rules

    def afterFlowable(self, flowable: Flowable):
        """Registers TOC entries."""
        if isinstance(flowable, Paragraph):
            flowable: Paragraph
            text = flowable.getPlainText()
            style = flowable.style.name

            if style in self._outline_levels:
                level = self._outline_levels[style]
            else:
                return

            if text not in self._bookmark_keys:
                key = text
                self._bookmark_keys.append(key)
            else:
                # There might headings with identical text, yet they need a different key
                # Keys are stored in a list and incremented if a duplicate is found
                cnt = 1
                while True:
                    key = text + str(cnt)
                    if key not in self._bookmark_keys:
                        self._bookmark_keys.append(key)
                        break
                    cnt += 1

            if isinstance(flowable, SmartParagraph):
                # Only smart paragraphs know their own position
                x, y = flowable.get_pos()
                y += flowable.style.fontSize + 15
                self.canv.bookmarkPage(key, fit="FitH", top=y)
            else:
                # Dumb paragraphs need to show the whole page
                self.canv.bookmarkPage(key)

            self.canv.addOutlineEntry(title=text, key=key, level=level)

    def _endBuild(self):
        """Override of parent function. Shows outline tree by default when opening PDF."""
        super(CustomDocTemplate, self)._endBuild()
        self.canv.showOutline()

story = list()
story.append(SmartParagraph('First Smart Heading', getSampleStyleSheet()['h1']))
story.append(Paragraph('Text in first heading'))
story.append(Spacer(1, 0.5 * cm))
story.append(SmartParagraph('First Sub Smart Heading', getSampleStyleSheet()['h2']))
story.append(Paragraph('Text in first sub heading'))
story.append(Spacer(1, 0.5 * cm))
story.append(Paragraph('Second Sub Dumb Heading', getSampleStyleSheet()['h2']))
story.append(Paragraph('Text in second sub heading'))
story.append(PageBreak())
story.append(Paragraph('Last Dumb Heading', getSampleStyleSheet()['h1']))
story.append(Paragraph('Text in last heading', PS('body')))
doc = CustomDocTemplate('mintoc.pdf')
doc.multiBuild(story)
```